Quicksight SUM of calculated field
I have the below calculated field in Quicksight that finds the max order amount per expense ID and produces the below table. I want to create another calculated field to put in a KPI that will count the sum of the order_amount
order_amount = max({Order Amount},[{Expense ID}])

I try to use this to find the sum : sum({Order Amount}, [{At ID}, {Expense ID}]) but it doesnt work.
Also this: sum(max({Order Amount}, [{At ID}])) gives me the below error.
Visual agg functions can't be used operands of as Level Aware Calculation (LAC) agg functions
How to achieve this?

You can try to use sumOver()

Create a new calculated field (eg Sum of Max Order Amounts).

Use below formula to sum the maximum values
sumOver({order_amount}, [{At ID}])


